# How to define a MACRO

Tags: c

How can I define a 40 bit MACRO.

For eg, if I want to define "deadbeef" (32 bit ) as a MACRO I'll do:

#define MYMACRO 0xdeadbeef

But how do I do it if I want to define "deadbeefs" ( 40 bits).

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  `0xdeadbeef` is a 32-bit hexadecimal value.  `"deadbeefs"` is a 9-character string literal (10 if you include the null-terminator).  What do you want to do with this string?

Answer (score 3):

you can't because s can't be represented in 4 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using a 40 bits long constant. For example (on a 64bits architecture):

```
#define MYMACRO 0xdeadbeeffL
```

If requires your compiler and your architecture to have a type able to store more than 40 bits. Here I used the long int type which is long enough on 64 bits architectures.

Comment: **Some** 64-bit architectures. Windows is a notable exception.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately C doesn't support base 29 literals.